# Count of occurrence of a string group by day in Google spreadsheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have table data in Google Spreadsheet something like this:

```
Date|Diet
4-Jan-2020|Coffee
4-Jan-2020|Snacks
4-Jan-2020|xyz
4-Jan-2020|Coffee
5-Jan-2020|Snacks
5-Jan-2020|abc
6-Jan-2020|Coffee
6-Jan-2020|Snacks
```

This table is a list of food items I had on a daily basis. I would like to get the number of times I had coffee on a daily basis. So I would like to get the output like this:

```
Date | No of times I had Coffee    
4-Jan-2020| 2
5-Jan-2020| 0
6-Jan-2020| 1
```

I used this query to get the output.

```
=query(A1:B1425,"select A, COUNT(B) where B='Coffee' group by A")
```

With this query, I get the below output. Do note that I don't get those days when I didn't have coffee

```
4-Jan-2020| 2
6-Jan-2020| 1
```

So count for 5-Jan-2020 is missing because there is no string "Coffee" for that day.

How do I get the desired output including the count 0? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")), 
  IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")), 
 QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select A,count(B) 
  where B='Coffee' 
  group by A 
  label count(B)''"), 2, 0))*1})
```

[image]

---

or try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:B, IF(B1:B="coffee", 1, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3)
  where Col1 is not null  
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)''"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change the counter into an If statement.
Something like "IF(COUNT(B) where B='Coffee' group by A">0,COUNT(B) where B='Coffee' group by A",0).
That will force the counter to have an actual value (0), even when nothing is found

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work. However, the query provided by the user "player0" solved. Thanks for your response.